# Taking a bytearray and creating and writing a JPEG

Tags: java, byte

I have a program that

1. Accepts an encoded base64 string
2. Converts it to a byte array.

It does this fine.

The final step involves writing this byte array to a file. For example C:\example.jpg.
I know simply writing the bytes won't work so was not sure what I would need to do to take the byte array and create a jpg with the picture that is coming in.

I have to actually send the picture as an attachment in email, but for testing purposes wanted to see if I can see a file saved and when I open up the jpg opens up. Thanks.

Comment: Did you really base64 encode a JPEG byte stream?

Comment: What format are the bytes in?  If they're already in jpeg format, then you should be able to write the byte array to a file with the correct name.

Comment: Why do you think that writing those bytes to file won't work?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing you're in need of something like this?

```
BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read( new ByteArrayInputStream( byteArray ) );
ImageIO.write(image, "BMP", new File("filename.bmp"));
```

Check out this question and answer, that's where I acquired it from:
[How to create a BMP file from raw byte[] in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1193748/how-to-create-a-bmp-file-from-raw-byte-in-java)

Comment: BufferedImage img = ImageIO.read(new ByteArrayInputStream(image));
File outputfile = new File("saved.jpg");   ImageIO.write(img, "jpg", outputfile);  I had the following but file is empty.