# YuvImage to Drawable

Tags: android, image-processing, android-view, android-image, android-drawable

I have byte[] data in YUV format and I would like to create a Drawable.

The long way to do it is to convert it to RGB -> Bitmap -> BitmapDrawable.

An easier way would be to create YuvImage, but is it possible to create a Drawable out of it without using compressing it into a jpeg?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Interesting discussion -> [Converting YUV->RGB(Image processing)->YUV during onPreviewFrame in android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9325861/converting-yuv-rgbimage-processing-yuv-during-onpreviewframe-in-android)

Alternately, you can also convert your bytes to a ColorMatrix and use **setYUV2RGB()**